# Display non ascii (Japanese) characters in pandas plot legend

Tags: python, unicode, matplotlib, pandas

If I do this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame( data=nr.random( (2,2) ), columns=[u'é',u'日本'] ).plot()
```

Result:

[image]

So `é` shows up, but not `日本`. After googling a bit, I found this [page](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/knaka20blue/20101118/1290070225) which seems to provide a solution for `matplotlib`. I downloaded the font file [here](http://ipafont.ipa.go.jp/ipafont/download.html#en) and got it to work with `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='/Users/user/Downloads/IPAfont00303/ipag.ttf')
plt.plot( np.arange(10), np.arange(10), label=u'日本' )
plt.legend( prop=prop )
```

Result:

[image]

Then I tried to apply the same solution to `pandas`:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='/Users/user/Downloads/IPAfont00303/ipag.ttf')
df0.plot( prop=prop )
```

Result:

```
TypeError: There is no line property "prop"
```

I understand the error message, but I don't know how I can get pandas to use `prop=prop`. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

df = pd.DataFrame( data=np.random.random( (2,2) ), columns=[u'é',u'日本'] )
ax = df.plot()
legend = ax.legend()
font = font_manager.FontProperties(fname='/Users/user/Downloads/IPAfont00303/ipag.ttf')

for text in legend.texts:
    text.set_font_properties(font)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hm. I'm sorry. I'm not able to reproduce the problem... but I'm not very familiar with the IPython notebook either. All I can say is the above code works for me if I run `ipython notebook`, start a new notebook, and dump all the code above into one cell and run it. That produces an external window. `%matplotlib inline` makes the figure appear embedded in the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Install and import japanize_matplotlib along with matplotlib, and all the Japanese characters will be accessible by matplotlib.

**Install**

```
pip install japanize_matplotlib
```

**Import**

```
import japanize_matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot

df = pd.DataFrame( data=np.random.random( (2,2) ), columns=['イチ', '二'] )
ax = df.plot(title="ひらがな")
```

**Output:**
[image]