# Writing Greek in matplotlib labels, titles

Tags: python, unicode, matplotlib

I am trying to write some text in Greek for labels, figure title etc. to accompany my plots but so far to no avail.

I don't want to print specific letters (I know how to do this using the special characters notation), I'd rather write the whole text in Greek (probably using Unicode and `u'text'` ?).

Before receiving suggestions I would like to mention that for some reason I can't get matplotlib to cooperate with TeX (using Ipython notebook from anaconda in Ubuntu 14.10), so that wouldn't really be an option.

I tried loading Arial font and it does load successfully but again I get square blocks instead of characters. I used

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf')
```

and then for displaying the string I used `u'Αποτελέσματα προσομοίωσης'`. Arial is supposed to render Greek perfectly and I have used it many times in text editors.

Comment: Did you review the [preexisting questions on matplotlib and unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib+unicode) yet?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, of course I did. It gives inconsistent results. Only a few characters are printed as supposed to, the rest are displayed as rectangles.

Comment: Exactly like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197124/display-non-ascii-japanese-characters-in-pandas-plot-legend) you mean?

Comment: To be honest I hadn't seen that. So do you propose to load a font of my own and see if it works?

Comment: Perhaps. You haven't shown us what you did try and what the output was, vs. what you expected. But if you are getting square blocks instead then it sounds like your font isn't handling those codepoints.

Comment: I tried loading Arial font and it does load successfully but again I get square blocks. I used import `matplotlib.font_manager as fm`
`prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf')` and then for displaying the string I used `u'string text goes here'` Arial is supposed to render greek perfectly and I have used it many times in text editors.

Comment: You probably want to [edit] your question to include all that.

Comment: To the downvoter, sorry but I believe that doing so is not fair unless a clear answer to the question (which is very specific) resides somewhere on the internet.

Comment: No need to add 'update' labels; we can all see the edit history just fine without those. What actual text are you using? `string text goes here` is not Greek.

Comment: does it really matter what the actual text is? it is "Αποτελέσματα προσομοίωσης" if that makes any sense to you.

Comment: Your question is much better for containing something people can try to reproduce; by including actual text and code *you help people help you*.

Comment: That's reasonable, I apologize for my tone. I just thought that unless one speaks Greek it wouldn't be of any use.

Comment: Consider adding a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to illustrate what problem you see, perhaps with a screenshot of the wrong output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by doing the following:

First, you have to import the necessary libraries and set a font installed on the computer that can for sure render Greek, like the Ubuntu font (Ubuntu Bold in the following code).

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
fp1 = fm.FontProperties(fname='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf')
```

then you can specifically apply the chosen font to each label, title etc as follows:

```
plt.title(u"Τίτλος του γραφήματος",fontproperties=fp1)
```

If that doesn't seem to work, try adding the following line at the beginning of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

A sample plot is provided to prove the correctness of the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
import numpy as np

fp1 = fm.FontProperties(fname='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf')

data = np.random.randn(5000) #generate some random data
plt.plot(data)
plt.title(u"Τίτλος του γραφήματος", fontproperties=fp1)
plt.xlabel(u"Άξονας x", fontproperties=fp1)
plt.ylabel(u"Άξονας y", fontproperties=fp1)
plt.show()
```

It should give you something like that:

[image: Example Graph]

Comment: please remember to accept your own answer when the system will let you

Comment: are you using python 2.x? then you could also add 
`__from__ future import unicode_literals`, then you don't have to type the u all the time.

Comment: yes I am using 2.7. That's actually very useful, thank you! maybe you mean `from __future__ import unicode_literals` though, right?