# How to use Unicode fonts other than English as bar plot labels from a dataframe with foreign characters?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with non-English fonts as below:

```
patient    opinion
   A          լավ
   B        շատ վատ
   C          լավ
   D        շատ լավ
   E          լավ
```

How to create a bar plot of a particular column with categorical data which are all in foreign characters. When the following command is entered:

```
df['opinion'].value_counts().plot(kind = "bar")
```

a bar plot is drawn but the categories from the column do not get printed correctly. Apart from translating the categories into English, what can be done to incorporate the non-ASCII characters in the bar plot?

Comment: Can you see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197124/display-non-ascii-japanese-characters-in-pandas-plot-legend basically you may need to use the font manager to load your font first

Comment: Cannot make it work